# How can I merge multiple tabs in a Google Spreadsheet using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I merge multiple tabs in a Google Spreadsheet using Google App Script ? Data in all the tabs keep changing.

For example, I have 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2' and 'Sheet3' in a Google spreadsheet. Data in all these sheets have 3 columns - Name and email ID & Region. Now, I want to merge/combine the data present in these 3 sheets/tabs into a 4th Sheet i.e. 'Sheet 4' having same Columns (name, email Id & Region). The 4th sheet should have data as - data of Sheet1 followed by Sheet2 and then Sheet3. The number of rows in all the 3 sheets keeps changing.

Comment: For e.g. I have 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2' and 'Sheet3' in a Google spreadsheet. Data in all these sheets have 3 cols - Name and email ID & Region. Now, I want to merge/combine the data present in these 3 sheets/tabs into a 4th Sheet i.e. 'Sheet 4' having same Columns (name, email Id & Region). The 4th sheet should have data as - data of Sheet1 followed  by Sheet2 and then Sheet3. The number of rows in all the 3 sheets keeps changing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`=query({Sheet1!A1:C; Sheet2!A1:C; Sheet3!A1:C}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)`

I wouldn't use a script for this; the worksheet formulas are much faster, at least most of the time.
Make sure you use semicolons to separate the ranges. Semicolons are the End_Of_Row operator for array literals.

If you really want to use a script...

```
function combineSheets() {
  var sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var s3= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var s4= sApp.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  //  If Sheet4 doesn't exist you'll need to create it here.
  
  var s1values = s1.getRange(1,1,s1.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  var s2values = s2.getRange(1,1,s2.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  var s3values = s3.getRange(1,1,s3.getLastRow(),3).getValues();
  
  //  Now, we can put out all together and stuff it in Sheet4
  var s4values = [];
  s4values =  s1values.concat(s2values,s3values);
  s4.getRange(1,1,s4values.length,3).setValues(s4values);
}
```

Comment: I fixed the code, so it actually runs with the generic spreadsheet I created, three sheets just filled with random numbers, and one empty sheet. You will need to modify it for your own use case.

Comment: @soyp had the right idea, just check the first column of each row. I used one filter to scan the combined array for blank A1 values, soup used the len() function to find the number of rows in each sheet, then combined them. which way is better or faster most likely depends on your context.

Comment: I think the formula should be: =filter({{Sheet1!A1:C500};{Sheet2!A1:C500};{Sheet3!A1:C500}};{{Sheet1!A1:A500};{Sheet2!A1:A500};{Sheet3!A1:A500}}<>"")
It had a , instead of ; there.

Comment: @AndréGil that comma is the separator for the filter function parameters. It's not in either array structure.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a script for this. In the fourth sheet, enter the following formula in A2:

```
={filter(Sheet1!A2:C, len(Sheet1!A2:A)); filter(Sheet2!A2:C, len(Sheet2!A2:A)); filter(Sheet3!A2:C, len(Sheet3!A2:A))}
```

It returns the contents of columns A-C where the entry in column A is nonempty, and stacks them in one array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Apps Scripts for this.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function TotalsSheet() {
  var totaldata = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var totalSheets = 2;

  for (var i=0; i < totalSheets; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();

    for (var row in values) {
      totaldata.push(values[row]);
    }
  }
  return totaldata; 
}

function Start() {
  var All = ss.insertSheet("All-Values");
  var totaldata = TotalsSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < totaldata.length; i++) {
    All.appendRow(totaldata[i]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch, I have made your change.

Comment: Note that inserting a new sheet each time may not be the desired behavior, especially with the same name ([`Spreadsheet#getSheetByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) will only return the left-most sheet with a given name...). You should probably only insert a sheet if it didn't already exist

Answer (score 2):

//This Script is must faster

```
function consolidateData(){

  // defined all variables
  var sheetNames = [];
  var dataSheet = [];
  var dataValues = [];
  var conso=[];
  var header = [["Name","email ID","Region"]];
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get all sheets
  var allsheets = ws.getSheets();

  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];    
    sheetNames[s] = sheet.getName();
    dataSheet[s] = ws.getSheetByName(sheetNames[s]);

    // adding all sheet's data to a single variable
    conso = conso.concat(dataSheet[s].getRange("A2:C"+dataSheet[s].getLastRow()).getValues());  
  }

  // writing data into new sheet
  var newSheet = ws.insertSheet().setName("Consolidated_Data");
      newSheet.getRange("A1:C1").setValues(header);
      newSheet.getRange("A2:C"+(conso.length+1)).setValues(conso);  




}
```

Answer (score -1):

I made one that will do nine tabs' consolidation, with more rows and columns.

```
=filter({{Sheet1!A1:Q500};{Sheet2!A1:Q500};{Sheet3!A1:Q500};{Sheet4!A1:Q500};{Sheet5!A1:Q500};{Sheet6!A1:Q500};{Sheet7!A1:Q500};{Sheet8!A1:Q500};{Sheet9!A1:Q500}},{{Sheet1!A1:A500};{Sheet2!A1:A500};{Sheet3!A1:A500};{Sheet4!A1:A500};{Sheet5!A1:A500};{Sheet6!A1:A500};{Sheet7!A1:A500};{Sheet8!A1:A500};{Sheet9!A1:A500}}<>"")
```

I'm wondering if it is a way to generalize the initial filter formula so that you can cut and paste in more sheet numbers, so for instance if there were 20 or 30 tabs with 25 columns, could you consolidate that easily into one page?