# GoogleForms response to Next Blank Line in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to place GoogleForms responses in the next blank line of a specific sheet (See [Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing)). Having some trouble using [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429303/script-to-populate-googleforms-response-in-multiple-locations) from @Mr.Rebot: the script attached to my GoogleSheets file seems to be missing something, as it is not producing any visible results.

NOTE: Project's trigger = `onEdit` ||| `From spreadsheet` ||| `On form submit`

See below for current code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var form = FormApp.openById('1YLnK8kw2dRMUUvL1l3s4qjz9fSRIe7kj92MlPV5WV5M');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
         (i + 1).toString(),
         itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
         itemResponse.getResponse());
   }
 }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.insertRowAfter(ss.getLastRow());
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).copyTo(ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1));
}
```

Comment: Kind of like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727196/how-can-i-merge-multiple-tabs-in-a-google-spreadsheet-using-google-app-script?rq=1), but automatically onEdit, and sorting by `Column A`